# How to access @metadata inside of Elasticsearch Output Script Field

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

Using the elasticsearch output module, I have `doc_as_upsert` set to `true` for many update actions. I'm using the @metadata capability to store the fields which I don't want upserting into ES.

However, I'm having trouble accessing fields inside of @metadata inside the Elasticsearch script function. The below script makes sure the `urls` array is less than 1,001 and also makes sure the new URL being added is unique to the array:

```
output {
   elasticsearch{
      hosts => "***************"
      user => "****"
      index => "****"
      password => "*********"
      document_type => "document"
      document_id => "%{[@metadata][domain]}"
      action => "update"
      script => 'if(ctx._source.urls.length < 1001){ boolean match = false; for (url in ctx._source.urls){if (url == params.event.get("[@metadata][url]")){match = true;}} if(match==false){ctx._source.urls.add(params.event.get("[@metadata][url]"));}}'
      doc_as_upsert => true
   }
}
```

Inside of ES, the URL value gets appended simply as NULL. I viewed the url metadata field inside of rubydebug and it is for sure being added. I can't reference the metadata directly `%{[@metadata][domain]}` because I run into script compilation errors for too many generated scripts.

Is there any way to access the `metadata.url` field inside of the script function for elasticsearch output plugin?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You cant use `@metadata` fields with output plugins, they are not sent (that the aim of metadata).

So, you could add a mutate filter or a ruby filter to copy metadata fields to event data:

```
ruby {
    code => 'event.get("[@metadata][rabbitmq_headers]").each {|k,v| event.set(k, v)}'
}
```